# responsive grid width different height columns

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

I'm trying to recreate this:

[image]

Using HTML/CSS, so that each coloured block is a div that I can add content into.  It needs to be responsive, but I think I can work that out using Media Queries.

I've managed to get the layout working for all blocks, apart from the bottom left one!  I just can't get it to slot into the gap under the top left block.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="box three">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="box four">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="box five">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="box six">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
}

.one {
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  width:40%;
  height:400px;
}
.two {
  background:#ddd;
  color:#000;
  width:60%;
  height:200px;
}
.three {
  background:#efefef;
  color:#000;
  width:30%;
  height:400px;
}
.four {
  background:#222;
  color:#fff;
  width:30%;
  height:200px;
}
.five {
  background:#754;
  color:#fff;
  width:30%;
  height:200px;
}
.six {
  background:#c3d;
  color:#fff;
  width:30%;
  height:200px;
}
```

I set it up in Codepen:

https://codepen.io/maniac123/pen/oQbgMr

Anyone know how to get that final "6" div to slot in under "1"?

Comment: Do you heard about css grid? It is exactly for this case

Comment: No, Maybe you can post an answer showing it would be used to create this grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use CSS Grid. Then I'd recommend using it. Plus, it makes the code a lot easier to handle.

Here's the css:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "one two two"
    "one three four"
    "five three six";
}

.box{
  min-height: 200px;
}

.one {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    grid-area: one;
}
.two {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    grid-area: two;
}
.three {
    background: #efefef;
    color: #000;
    grid-area: three;
}
.four {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    grid-area: four;
}
.five {
    background: #754;
    color: #fff;
    grid-area: five;
}
.six {
    background: #c3d;
    color: #fff;
    grid-area: six;
}
```

And here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQLOxy

In my example, I'm using named grid areas. If you want to swap one of the blocks positions with another. You can swap their `grid-area` properties.

If you do choose this option, I'd recommend you look more into CSS Grid, as it makes life a lot easier. Here's an article where you can read up on it more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer

Comment: No problem, happy to help! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

`<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="width: 40%;">
    <div class="one" style="width: 100%;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="six" style="width: 100%;">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="box three">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="box four">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="box five">
    5
  </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS-grid,

I would suggest looking into it before anything else..

but here is how it could be done:

```
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.box-one{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

where colums is going left to right, and rows is top to bottom

this will only do the first one , the rest should be done in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using fixed heights for the blocks, you could use the following:

```
.six {
margin-top: -200px;
...
}
```

I would recommend having a look at CSS Grid though.